# Show image in different dimensions

Tags: css, html, xhtml

i have a 100x100px image and i need to show that in 3 different dimensions in html,

50x50 60x60 70x70

so my dubt is if better to save img in 3 dimensions then do not use css or html width and height or if to use same img with css rules about dimensions... which solution is faster rendered ?

Comment: Let me run a benchmark on my home server. I'd guess it depends on the browser. For simplicity's sake, I'd resize in CSS, though.

Comment: If all of the images will be displayed at the same time in one page.. do not resize it, use css instead.

Comment: Degradation does happen when you shrink or stretch the image in the browser - how bad it is, pretty much depends on the image. Try both methods and compare the result in a couple of browsers to see which works best.

Comment: uhmmm :p ... i can agree if dimensions are not square :) , i have 100x100 and i need to show that in 60x60 , 50x50 , 70x70 all dimensions are squared from the original and smaller then original ;)

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

If you are using the same image, Only 1 time image cache is required by the browser. So If you are displaying more than 1 type of image in the same page then dont go for multiple images. Otherwise go for multiple images.

But honestly, 100x100 if you have, It should not be a problem to load. Only in slow connections it will be problem (<128kbps). Otherwise i dont see a considerable difference.

Comment: thanks and what about is better using css rules or html tags? :)

Comment: That is hard to answer. Use CSS if its a style box, Or something which you may re-use (CSS classes) a lot. Use images if you are putting it in a div tag. Or want it to be a actual photo. But again, quite difficult for me tell without the context.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry too much about rendering speed, the main difference you'll see is in terms of image quality.  Some browsers (Chrome) perform very high quality image interpolation, while others (IE, Firefox) opt for a faster algorithm that does not give as nice of a result.  So you'll get the best, most consistent image quality by having the three separate image files, one for each size.

That said, since you're only scaling from 100x100 to a minimum size of 50x50 you probably don't need to worry too much about interpolation artifacts either.  So I'd recommend just doing whatever is most convenient for you to implement.

And in terms of pure rendering speed, having the separate images will be faster, because no interpolation step is required in that case.  In terms of initial page-load speed, however, having a single image will be faster, because there is only 1 file to download instead of 3 (or 4).  As for using CSS or HTML tag attributes to set the width and height, there will be practically no difference in speed.  The expensive operation is the interpolation of the image itself, and it doesn't make much difference if you specify the interpolation through CSS or through tag attributes.